# python's mock return value of a method called within another method doesn't work

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to mock a method for unit testing like this:

**get_tree_test.py**

```
from company.marketing_tree import get_tree

class MidNightTests(TestCase):
 @mock.patch("company.analytics.get_fb_data", autospec=True)
    def test_first_midnight(self, mock_fb_data):
        mock_fb_data.return_value = {}
        get_tree()
```

**get_tree.py**

```
from company.analytics import get_fb_data

def get_tree():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    data_caller = executor.submit(get_data)
    info_caller = executor.submit(get_info)

def get_data():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    first_data = exeuctor.submit(get_fb_data)
```

I do see that `mock_fb_data.return_value = {}` is created as a mock object, but when I debug `get_data()` method I see that get_fb_data is a function and not a mock

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to patch the right place. Inside `get_tree`, you created a global name `get_fb_data`, which the code uses directly:

```
from company.analytics import get_fb_data
```

You need to patch *that name*, not the original `company.analytics.get_fb_data` name; patching works by replacing a name to point to the mock instead:

```
class MidNightTests(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("get_tree.get_fb_data", autospec=True)
    def test_first_midnight(self, mock_fb_data):
        mock_fb_data.return_value = {}
        get_tree()
```

See the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) of the `unittest.mock` documentation.